# Lightbox + Text under Image Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

How can I add custom text under each image when it's zoomed in? Now it is based on the `alt` text, but I want to customize it even more with images etc.

The perfect solution would be if the text was displayed in a `div`.

Here is the codepen:

```js
// Create a lightbox
(function() {
  var $lightbox = $("<div class='lightbox'></div>");
  var $img = $("<img>");
  var $caption = $("<p class='caption'></p>");

  // Add image and caption to lightbox

  $lightbox
    .append($img)
    .append($caption);

  // Add lighbox to document

  $('body').append($lightbox);

  $('.lightbox-gallery img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get image link and description
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var cap = $(this).attr("alt");

    // Add data to lighbox

    $img.attr('src', src);
    $caption.text(cap);

    // Show lightbox

    $lightbox.fadeIn('fast');

    $lightbox.click(function() {
      $lightbox.fadeOut('fast');
    });
  });

}());
```

```css
body{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #b81d1d, #5F554C, #E4DFD8);
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.container{
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 35px 50px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 85px 60px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.text-center{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.lightbox-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.lightbox-gallery div > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.lightbox-gallery div {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-basis: 180px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .lightbox-gallery {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .lightbox > div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}


/*Lighbox CSS*/


.lightbox{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 20;
 padding-top: 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lightbox img{
 display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.lightbox .caption{
 margin: 15px auto;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Lightbox Gallery</h2>
  <div class="lightbox-gallery">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f1b702/fff&text=image1" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, quae, quam. Ut dolorum quia, unde dicta at harum porro officia obcaecati ipsam deserunt fugit dolore delectus quam, maxime nisi quo."></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/d2f1b2/222&text=image2" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime accusamus officiis dignissimos doloribus consectetur harum eos sapiente optio aut minima."></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/eee/000&text=image3" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates veritatis similique, amet, maiores soluta recusandae cupiditate, sed perspiciatis fugit minima, sunt dolores cum earum deserunt illo ipsum!"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/222/fff&text=image4" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque laudantium dignissimos tenetur eos unde quidem repellat officiis nemo laboriosam necessitatibus deleniti commodi quis aliquid est atque tempora aut, nihil!"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/b47f99/000&text=image5" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto minus consequatur soluta quaerat itaque, laboriosam quis a facilis, cumque, deleniti quas aperiam voluptate dolore. Enim nostrum sit eaque, porro eligendi illo placeat?"></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e1d400/000&text=image6" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi suscipit quam, id aliquam totam aperiam quas rem debitis voluptatem pariatur, illo accusamus facilis eius ipsa! Reprehenderit libero, quas iste repudiandae distinctio, quos dignissimos."></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Codepen URL: http://codepen.io/lkfmarketing/pen/XMdNEP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden `div` and grab the text with jQuery.

```
 <div class="js-text text">Test</div>
 var txt = $(this).parent().find('.js-text').text()
```

[Forked example](https://codepen.io/jonathandion/pen/EmPbvb)

Comment: This is great! When I add an `img` in between <div class="js-text text">Test</div> it doesn't show up in the overlay. It should be a small profile image showing who has taken the picture. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I updated the demo. Try to click on the first image.

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you could use data attributes:

```
<div><img id="myImg" src="http://placehold.it/300/f1b702/fff&text=image1" alt="my alt" data-caption="my Caption or whatever you want"></div>
```

And then you use this in js as follows

```
var myCaption = $('#myImg').data('caption');
// use this as you please
```

Regards